How to push to state and reflect in effect
I am trying to make a simple task list (a to-do list with a different name).
When I click a TaskAdder it calls the function add_task which is a string for now. This should update the effect in the TaskList function and rebuild the component with a list of tasks.
For example, I have the following list of tasks:
<div className="tasklist">
    <Task title="a" />
    <Task title="b" />
</div>

When I call add_task("c") it should update the list and be reflected in the DOM:
<div className="tasklist">
    <Task title="a" />
    <Task title="b" />
    <Task title="c" />
</div>

However I don't understand how to push to states and how to update the DOM with effect in a for loop.
let [task_list, setTask_list] = useState([]);

export default function TaskList() {
    var output: ReactElement[] = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        task_list.forEach(e => {
            output.push(<Task title={e} />);
        });

        return () => {};
    }, [task_list]);

    return (
        <div className="tasklist">
            {output}
        </div>
    );
}

export function add_task(task: string) {
    task_list.push(task);
}


This is mutating state:
task_list.push(task);

Which (1) is the wrong approach and a common source of bugs in React, and (2) in no way signals to React that state has been updated and the component should re-render.
Make use of the setTask_list state setter function instead:
setTask_list([...task_list, task]);

Note specifically that in doing so we are not modifying the existing array but rather creating a new array and setting state to that.  This allows React to observe that the state has changed, since the two array references are different.

"TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'."
This might be because I am using tsx rather than jsx

@Player_X_YT: If you're using TypeScript then use TypeScript.  Specify a type for the state value: let [task_list, setTask_list] = useState<string[]>([]);

I am just starting out with typescript, that code fixed that error but I still can't add tasks from other components

@Player_X_YT: Nowhere in the code shown in the question are you attempting to add tasks from other components.  (And all of the code shown in the question really should be inside the component.)  That may merit an entirely different Stack Overflow question, in which you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Sharing state between components can be done in a few different ways.  You may want to look into the useContext hook.

David has answer to what to lookout for when handling list in React state -- do not mutate the state directly. However, there are a few more things

useState should live inside the React component
use .map() to render the list as rule of thumbs. The ability to add key to prop is important to let React know what children component are to re-render or not.

Also, your code can look better by
const OtherComponent = () => {
  // setState should live inside the React component
  const [task_list, setTask_list] = useState([])

  // don't mutate state, create a new list and set it to the state
  const handleAddTask = (task: string) => {
    setTask_list((prevTask) => [...prevTask, task])
  }

  return (
    <>
      // ... component code. apply yours here
      <TaskList task_list={task_list} />
    </>
  )
}

export default function TaskList({task_list}) {
  return (
    <div className="tasklist">
      {task_list.map((list, i) => (
        <Task title={list} key={i} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}


Example Codesandbox

Good catch.  I'm honestly surprised that using the useState hook outside of a component didn't produce an error.  The OP may not be showing us accurate code.

If my state is inside of the component, how can I modify it from a different file?

@David That is the code (minus imports) many parts of js try to figure out what you mean and auto correct as best as the interpreter can
Edit: It did throw an error I didn't see

@Player_X_YT Gotcha, so that state is from another component. Updating the answer accordingly

@TaiweiTuan sorry, I meant that the state is a part of TaskList but it should be modified by a different component in a different file

@Player_X_YT I've updated the answer and the link to CodeSandbox. Let me know if you have more question :)


However I don't understand how to push to states and how to update the
DOM with effect in a for loop.


useEffect is an escape hatch in React system. It is used only to synchronise React components with external systems like non-React components or similar. You will be able to know more on this from here.

Just as in this case, in many of the cases, useEffect might not be required in a React component. There is an exhaustive description on this matter you can find here.

The List of tasks this app tries to update does not live in an external system, therefore useEffect may not be required in this case. Instead The Tasks list can be rendered in response to the reactive changes in the same component itself. The point 5 adds more to this point.

While updating JavaScript objects, it needs to be done without mutation. In simple words, always replace or recreate the object itself. More can find here.

React provides a declarative way to manipulate the UI. Therefore a React app will never update DOM directly. Instead the app is supposed to declare the various states it can be in, and switch between them in response to the user inputs. You can know more from here .


The sample code follows the principles we discussed above. Please try to see if it is useful.
App.js
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

export default function TaskList() {
  const [newtask, setNewTask] = useState('');
  const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState([]);

  function handleAddtoList() {
    setTaskList([...taskList, newtask]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>New task</label>
      <input
        value={newtask}
        onChange={(e) => setNewTask(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={handleAddtoList}>Add to List</button>
      <hr></hr>
      <label>Taks list</label>
      <div>
        {taskList.map((task) => (
          <Fragment key={task}>
            <Task title={task} />
            <br></br>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function Task({ title }) {
  return <label>{title}</label>;
}

Test run:
npm start

Test results:


Hi, Thank you for your vote. If possible, please let me know the reason for your valuable vote, so that I would be able to improve it further.

I am not the one who voted, but the original requirements were that 1. typescript it used, 2. The list is modified by a different component

Hi, Thank you for your response. As you know typescript does not have any impact in the run time, wherein there is only JavaScript. In my MRE, i was taking this approach. Did you find the 5 points in the post useful ? In the sample code, it has been refactored on the following basis - useEffect hook and the object mutation have been avoided. The sample code produces results as you can see in the output enclosed. If you are in need of further assistance, please comment.
